# I have a problem Error Code 1064 MySQL SHOW INDEX

Tags: mysql

I'm doing an example of this webpage

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-show-indexes/

I can't run the query due to the *Error Code: 1064*

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'INVISIBLE,

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
        contact_id  INT             AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first_name  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
        last_name   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
        email       VARCHAR(100),
        phone       VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(contact_id),
        UNIQUE(email),
        INDEX phone(phone) INVISIBLE,
        INDEX name(first_name, last_name) comment 'By first name and/or last name'
);
```

This is a screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5s1Z.png)

This is my version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOhQW.png)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INVISIBLE only exsits in Mysql 8

so leave it out when you have some thing older like 5.7

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
        contact_id  INT             AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first_name  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
        last_name   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
        email       VARCHAR(100),
        phone       VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(contact_id),
        UNIQUE(email),
        INDEX phone(phone) ,
        INDEX name(first_name, last_name) comment 'By first name and/or last name'
);
```

why not use mysql 8, but the INVISIBLE has no use, besides that the optimizer will ignore it, if you want to simulate this you FORCE the other index  or even better `IGNORE INDEX (phone)`which has the same effect

Comment: If I remove the "INVISIBLE" it will run, But as a beginner on MYSQL I want to fix this issue and run with the "INVISIBLE" to see the result as is shows on the link page.

Comment: But the way I'm using a new "schema" just for the examples.

Comment: why not use mysql 8, but the invisble has no use, besides that the optimizer will ignore it. So you can use IGNORE INDEX (phone)